# Debian Sparc on Sunfire 240V recommended?

Tags: debian, hardware-compatibility

We're working on a Sunfire V240 server with SunOS 5.9 (Solaris 9, yeah really old one),  I'd like your advices about installing Debian Sparc on those systems.
Is this a good choice, could we even install Solaris Sparc 11 other wise, what about compatibility?

Comment: Debian works great on Sparc servers, see [Debian Sparc Port](http://www.debian.org/ports/sparc/). I can't tell about the recent release, though. My Sparc systems still run lenny. If it's a good choice depends on your needs and what you expect from an operating system.

Comment: Thank you Marco, my needs are basically use LAMP on it and include PostgreSQL too. I guess it could be fine and performance too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Solaris 10 is supported and Solaris 11 isn't.

I would personally consider getting Solaris 10 if the pricing is acceptable.   Using an operating system supported by the hardware vendor is usually a very good idea, and Solaris 10 is a really good version.

That said, Debian is really nice - I love `apt-get` - so if you want to leave Solaris that would be a good choice.  Be aware that disks will need to be erased so you need tested backups (rsync and tar are good tools for this) and large downtime windows.

Please let us know how it goes.

Comment: Really helpfull Thorbjrn! I appreciate it

Comment: Re Solaris Pricing. Judging from the age of this box and the fact that it hasn't seen any OS upgrade since the dawn of day I would guess this non-production. In that case you can use Solaris for free. Read the [Solaris license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html) for more specific info.